# how to turn off volume with MPMusicPlayerController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

could MPMusicPlayerController turns off volume at once ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean make it silent.

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0.0];
```